# .length not working on $resource result in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting my $resource getAll() as

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
0: Resource
1: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

and I am using a service to save data to its object as

```
this.datas = [];
this.nestedData = [];
this.setdata = function(datas) {
    this.datas = datas;
    console.log(this.datas); // get data as mentioned above
    console.log(this.datas.length); // here i get length as 0
    for(var i=0;i < datas.length; i++) {
        this.nestedData.push(datas[i].nested);
    }
};
```

Why do I get length as 0? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using same name like datas

```
this.datas = [];//Or use this.datas = {};
this.nestedData = [];
this.setdata = function(data) {//Changed name datas to data
    this.datas = data;
    console.log(this.datas); 
    console.log(this.datas.length);
    for(var i=0;i < datas.length; i++) {
        this.nestedData.push(datas[i].nested);
    }
};
```